# Using QWebView with a static build of Qt

Tags: macos, qt

Is it possible to access QtWebKit when Qt has been configured to link statically? I can use QWebView easily on a dynamic Qt, but when I use the `-static` flag to configure Qt, QtWebKit does not get built. Can that be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how it is done in [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). We include a copy of Qt and WebKit (for many reasons irrelevant here) and build everything statically. The end result is one single PhantomJS executable on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.

Comment: Hi, please submit a script for phantomJS which execute a statically with webkit.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit a script"? I suggest looking at the project and study its build system.

Answer (score 0):

It gets disabled because static builds of WebKit have been broken for quite a while now. It can be done if you fix the problems yourself. There doesn't seem to be any interest upstream (Apple) to fix the issues.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Apple. See my other answer.

Comment: Hi, I want to navigate Microsoft excel file .xlsx in web Browser.But static Qt is not support web kit .So you can any idea in qt design control which show preview of excel(xlsx) file.